# Enable spell checker in AEM 6.0

Tags: aem

I am using AEM 6.0 trail version.I want to enable spell checker for search but not able to figure out how to do it .
I was able to enable spell checker in 5.6 Licensed version by adding 
`<param name="spellCheckerClass" value="com.day.crx.core.query.spell.CRXSpellChecker$OneMinuteRefreshInterval"/>` to workspace.xml

But in AEM 6.0 I am not able to locate workspace.xml.Is this because I am using trail version

Answer (score 1):

AEM 6 is based on JCR OAK and it uses Apache Solr as a search engine, where as in AEM 5.6.1 or older version has JCR repository and Apache Lucene as a search engine.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the current version of AEM 6.0 does not support the spellcheck feature.  I learned this the hard way.  From my understanding, AEM 6.0 SP2 still uses OAK 1.0.9.  Spellcheck support in OAK has being added in 1.1.0

But here the information on how to at least enable SolR search in AEM 6.0 (which is still better than the normal JCR search) and you should be ready for the spellcheck support when it happens

http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/deploy/upgrade/queries-and-indexing.html

To enable the spellcheck in SolR you can look at the SolR Spellchecker documentation

If my understanding is correct, OAK 1.1 should use the SolR spellcheck if it is there.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OAK-2175